# fft3d, swapped slice, need to transpose?

Tags: c++, matlab, swap, transpose, fftw

I need to perform a 2-step ifft3d in c++ by using fftw library.

```
1st step: a one dimensional ifft across third dimension, creating a "hybrid_kspace"
...
[some operations with hybrid_kspace]
...
2nd step: a two dimensional ifft over horizontal slices of hybrid_kspace.
```

According this (https://cmb.ornl.gov/members/z8g/csproject-report.pdf) I have to perform some kind of transpose operation, but I don't really get this.

So I tried to study this problem in Matlab and something rather strange occurred (see code). First and last slice of Clown3D image are swapped and I don't understand why.

```
load clown;
Z=5;
Clown3D=repmat(X,[1,1,Z]);
white=max(Clown3D(:));
Clown3D(100,:,1)=white; %1 white row
Clown3D([70,130],:,2)=white; %2 white row
Clown3D([50 100 150],:,3)=white; %3 white row
Clown3D([40 80 120 160],:,4)=white; %4 white row
Clown3D([30 60 90 120 150],:,5)=white; %5 white row

%Original 3d image
for ii=1:Z
    figure, imagesc(Clown3D(:,:,ii)), colormap gray
end

%into fourier space
Kspace=fftshift(fftn(fftshift(Clown3D)));    

%2-step ifft3d
K_hybrid3D = fftshift(ifft(fftshift(Kspace,3),[],3),3);

ReconClown3D=zeros(size(Clown3D));
for ii=1:Z
    B=squeeze(K_hybrid3D(:,:,ii));
    A = fftshift(ifftn(fftshift(B)));
    ReconClown3D(:,:,ii)=A;
end

for ii=1:Z
    figure, imagesc(abs(ReconClown3D(:,:,ii))), colormap gray
end

%classic ifft3d
ReconClown3DCalssic=fftshift(ifftn(fftshift(Kspace)));
for ii=1:Z
    figure, imagesc(abs(ReconClown3DCalssic(:,:,ii))), colormap gray
end
```

Comment: What do you mean "swapped"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swapping is happening because of your use of `fftshift` and lack of `ifftshift`. I recommend reading the [`fftshift` documentation here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html) and [`ifftshift` documentation here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifftshift.html). `ifftshift` is the inverse shifting operation for an `fftshift`. If you shift a vector or matrix with `fftshift`, you should be using `ifftshift` to unshift it or the output of an `ifft` of it, and vice versa. There is an excellent discussion of the correct way to do this in [this MathWorks thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/285244).

Every time you call `ifft`, you should first shift the argument using `fftshift` and then shift the output using `ifftshift` to get the correct result. When using `fft`, you should shift the input using `ifftshift` and shift the output using `fftshift`.

This distinction does not matter if the input is an even size, because `fftshift` and `ifftshift` are their own inverse in that case. However, your input has a dimension of 5, which is what causes the issue.

This gets a bit dicey for the portion where you're implementing the '2-step' ifft3d because of the mixing of different dimensions of `fft`. It looks like you're doing a 3D `fft`, a 1D `ifft`, and a 2D `ifft` in turn. I included a 'fix' for that in the code as well that does not follow the previous recommendations. Instead, it uses `fftshift` for the input and output of the 3D `fft`.

To fix your code, you should modify the lines involving shifting as stated previously. The resulting code is as follows:

```
load clown;
Z=5;
Clown3D=repmat(X,[1,1,Z]);
white=max(Clown3D(:));
Clown3D(100,:,1)=white; %1 white row
Clown3D([70,130],:,2)=white; %2 white row
Clown3D([50 100 150],:,3)=white; %3 white row
Clown3D([40 80 120 160],:,4)=white; %4 white row
Clown3D([30 60 90 120 150],:,5)=white; %5 white row

%Original 3d image
for ii=1:Z
    figure, imagesc(Clown3D(:,:,ii)), colormap gray
end

%into fourier space
%this line is kept as is; modifying it causes swapping.
Kspace=fftshift(fftn(fftshift(Clown3D)));

%2-step ifft3d
%Modified to include ifftshift, although it shouldn't matter here
K_hybrid3D = ifftshift(ifft(fftshift(Kspace,3),[],3),3);

ReconClown3D=zeros(size(Clown3D));
for ii=1:Z
    B=squeeze(K_hybrid3D(:,:,ii));
    %Modified to include ifftshift, although it shouldn't matter here
    A = ifftshift(ifftn(fftshift(B)));
    ReconClown3D(:,:,ii)=A;
end

for ii=1:Z
    figure, imagesc(abs(ReconClown3D(:,:,ii))), colormap gray
end

%classic ifft3d
%Modified to include ifftshift, and it DOES matter here.
ReconClown3DCalssic=ifftshift(ifftn(fftshift(Kspace)));
for ii=1:Z
    figure, imagesc(abs(ReconClown3DCalssic(:,:,ii))), colormap gray
end
```

Comment: thank you very much. very clear. This stuff about fftshift and ifftshift is so dark... :D

Comment: @user2835487 if this answer helped you, consider accepting it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work